# fixed distance and no page break between lines

Tags: page-breaking, memoir, quoting

I'm trying to make a quotation environment which puts the quote on a gray background, with a colored rule right on top of it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[papersize={100mm,100mm},noheadfoot,margin=25mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.7}
\newdimen\X\X=22pt\advance\X3\baselineskip
\newenvironment{Quote}%
   {\parindent0pt\parskip1\baselineskip%
    \par%
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{\hsize}{6pt}}\\[-\X]%
    \nopagebreak%
    \begin{quote}\noindent\leftmargin0pt\rightmargin0pt\begin{qshade}%
   }%
   {\end{qshade}\end{quote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Quote}A small quote\end{Quote}
\begin{Quote}A small quote\end{Quote}
%\begin{Quote}A small quote\end{Quote}
\end{document}
```

This works fine, but when I uncomment the third Quote, a page break occurs between the rule and the quotation, even though there is a \nopagebreak. 
Also, this introduces extra white between the rule and the shaded box of the other two Quote's. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Put `margin=20mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you to employ `mdframed` for this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[papersize={100mm,100mm},noheadfoot,margin=25mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.7}

\newenvironment{Quote}
  {\par\parindent0pt\parskip1\baselineskip
   \begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red,
     linewidth=6pt,
     backgroundcolor=shadecolor,
     bottomline=false,leftline=false,rightline=false]
   }
   {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Quote}A small quote\end{Quote}
\end{document}
```

This won't have any break between the red rule on top and the quotation.

[image]

Comment: wonderful, especially because I can set all inner- and outer margins. Thanks!